# Random 21/42 seconds timeout in outgoing traffic on Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application running in the azure german cloud as Azure Web App (single instance - Standard S3 size).
I'm calling a non azure hosted REST/SOAP service on a particular host and the web requests either succeed promptly or timeout after 21 / 42 seconds.
I've load tested the requests and the percentile of requests timing out is between 20 and 80.
One particular remarkable property of the timeout is, that they occur after exactly 21 or 42 seconds (this is serious, no reference to hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy intended).
Calling a different service from the web app works just fine, temporarily at least.
We've already checked the firewall of the non azure service and if the timeout occurs, not a single packet reached the host.

This issue occurred once in the past one year ago and support was unable to tell what the cause was until the issue suddenly went away roughly two weeks after first occuring, so the ticket got closed as fixed itself but now its back.

The code is using https://github.com/canton7/RestEase (uses HttpClient underneath) and looks like

```
[Header("Content-Type", "application/json")]
public interface IApi
{
    [Post("/Login")]
    Task<LoginToken> Login([Body]LoginRequest request);
}

private static Dictionary<string, IApi> ApiClientsByHost = new Dictionary<string, IApi>();

private IApi GetApiForHost(string host)
{
    if (!ApiClientsByHost.TryGetValue(host, out var client))
    {
        lock (ApiClientsByHost)
        {
            if (!ApiClientsByHost.TryGetValue(host, out client))
            {
                ApiClientsByHost[host] = client = RestClient.For<IApi>(host);
            }
        }
    }

    return client;
}

var client = GetApiForHost("https://production/");
var loginToken = await client.Login(new LoginRequest { Username = username, Password = password });
```

By different service, i mean using "https://testserver/" instead of "https://production/" (testserver is located in a different data center with different IP and all).
The API authentication is passing a token via query but it timeouts already before being able to get a token.
The code is caching the `IApi` to avoid the TCP starvation problems of disposing HttpClients (but i've never run into port exhaustion).
Restarting the app does not resolve the issue and the issue only occurs to production currently (but a year ago, when this issue occurred on production, we've switched to testserver which worked initially but after some time, ran into the same problem)

EDIT: Found some [explanation in the last answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4a8f7be5-5e15-4213-a7bb-ddf424a954e6/winhttpsendrequest-ends-with-12002-errorhttptimeout-after-21-seconds-no-matter-what-timeout?forum=windowssdk) as to where those magical 21 seconds are comming from.

EDIT: One way i've found to workaround is, is to setup a azure vm with a proxy on it and configure defaultProxy to pass through that vm.

Comment: Can you show the code that  issues the request? What kind of auth is involved, if any? When you say you can successfully call a different service, is that to the same target domain and/or server, or an entirely unrelated target?

Comment: @McGuireV10 i've edited the post

Comment: I was researching a totally unrelated problem and stumbled across [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/957) 2016 github issue where Azure Functions were timing out at exactly 21 seconds. No solution was found before it was closed but that specific timing is probably not a coincidence. You may want to broaden your search to Azure issues in general with 21 second timeouts. Very weird.

Comment: @McGuireV10 interesting, i shall do some more research in that direction... thanks

Comment: Very interesting find about that 21 second timeout and the underlying TCP / winsock code. Doesn't get much more obscure than that.

Comment: I had the same effect with Azure app service when we had rare requests. If request come smth like 1 per 10 minutes or less, Azure seems to drop the outgoing socket, which is cached in HttpClient. The solution for such case is to add 
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
so tcp connection is closed after request

Answer (score 0):

That's TCP retransmission timing out. It's odd that you are getting different values though.

Comment: And so, what to do? I have the same problem with part of the requests from azure to external url